# Passing DateTimeOffset as a part of the path in a GET request with WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

What will be the URL for this `Get` method?

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public string Get(DateTimeOffset startDate)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

The route template is

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{startDate}"
```

I tried to hit with URLs like

```
api/values/12Sept2013
api/values/2011-06-01T14:03:00+00:00Z
api/values/2011-12-13
```

nothing worked.. I even encoded the startDate with `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`, but won't work!

Any idea what is the correct format?

Answer (score 2):

something like this

```
~/api/values?startDate=2008%2F08%2F08
```

Comment: nope!!... it gives "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found" error...

Comment: well, moving the startDate parameter to querystring works... api/values?startDate=2013%2F08%2F08 works!.. thanks... i can live with it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer

To send a `DateTimeOffset` to your API, format it like this:

`2017-04-17T05:45:18.070Z`

The complete API URL will look like this:

`http://localhost:1234/api/values/startDate=2017-04-17T05:45:18.070Z`

By formatting it this in this manner, I am able to pass in a `DateTimeOffset` parameter to my `ApiController` that I made using Azure Mobile Services.

#### Code

You can use `ToString(yyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ)` to parse the DateTimeOffset.

```cs
var dateTimeOffsetAsAPIParameter = DateTimeOffset.Now.UtcDateTime.ToString("yyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ");

string.Format("http://localhost:1234/api/values/?startDate={0}", dateTimeOffsetAsAPIParameter);
```